# OpenCV iOS and 64bit architecture

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, opencv, armv7

I have my iOS project where I included `opencv2` iOS project.

When I tried to compile for iPhone 64bit (iPhone 5s) I had some linker errors.

Now I included into my project this version of opencv2 library as done in this project

[iPhone OCR Tesseract and OpenCV](https://github.com/samwize/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV)

and I setted

`$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` as `Architectures`

Is correct this way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

If it still helps the 25th April 2014 version of OpenCV (2.4.9) includes the 64-bit libraries.  If you grab it then you should be able to build with no problems on the iPhone 5s.